# Как сохранить картинку в модели, отправив её через ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Казалось бы простая задача: мне нужно через аякс отправить картинку на сервер (из формы), и там её сохранить в модели.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
        $('#form_img_hide_input').ajaxForm({
            success: function (data) {
                alert('data');
            }
        }).submit();
```

виевка

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_menu_choice_imgDef(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        f_file = request.FILES['test_file']
        
        pattern_save_imgModel.objects.create(field_img = f_file, )

        return HttpResponse('')
```

Вот, мои любимые. Наконец то))))))